# :after element with rotate moving on resize

Tags: html, css, shadow, pseudo-element

I have a :before and an :after element (for shadow purposes) with a transform: rotate applied to it. The :before stays in place when the viewport is resized, however the :after moves slightly up and down. If the rotate is removed, it stays in place on resize. How can I make it stay in place on resize with the roate?

I have put a z-index: 1 on the :before and :after for visibility of the issue

It's the shadow #3

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/details/jEYpyP/

HTML:

```
<h2>Shadow #3</h2>
<div class="row shadow-3">
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 160px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  display: block;
    img:nth-of-type(1) {
      content: url(http://marshall.org/wp-content/themes/marshall/img/featured-space-policy.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(2) {
      content: url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/09/04/1409790551890_wps_28_Astronaut_Reid_Wiseman_po.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(3) {
      content: url(http://cdn2.collective-evolution.com/assets/uploads/2014/08/life_in_space-728x400.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(4) {
      content: url(http://s.ngm.com/2007/10/space-travel/img/space_feature.jpg);
    }
}

img {
  width: 23%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shadow-box {
  width: 23%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    &:hover {
      transform: translateY(-4px);
    }
  }
}

.shadow-box:before, .shadow-box:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 8%;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-6deg) translate(calc(3% + 10px), 31px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow-box:after {
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(6deg) translate(126%, -146px);
}

.shadow-box:hover:before, .shadow-box:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px lighten($black, 40%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using translates is the way to go here, I'd set the container to position: relative; and then use absolute positioning to position the shadow things: http://jsfiddle.net/bpma9ko4/

Here the relevant parts:

```
.shadow-box {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.shadow-box:before, .shadow-box:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-6deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.shadow-box:after {
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(6deg);
  right: 20px;
  left: auto;
}
```

In your example, when I removed the translates, the red box on the right went underneath the image (on a new line) and then you tried dragging it up with translates, but to me it is a much more direct way if you just place it over the image to begin with, using the top/left/right attributes.

Note: My example is simplified, it doesn't have shadows and other things, it's cut down to the parts relevant to the question.

The whole code:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 160px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  display: block;
    img:nth-of-type(1) {
      content: url(http://marshall.org/wp-content/themes/marshall/img/featured-space-policy.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(2) {
      content: url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/09/04/1409790551890_wps_28_Astronaut_Reid_Wiseman_po.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(3) {
      content: url(http://cdn2.collective-evolution.com/assets/uploads/2014/08/life_in_space-728x400.jpg);
    }
    img:nth-of-type(4) {
      content: url(http://s.ngm.com/2007/10/space-travel/img/space_feature.jpg);
    }
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shadow-box {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.shadow-box:before, .shadow-box:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-6deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.shadow-box:after {
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(6deg);
    right: 20px;
    left: auto;
}

.shadow-box:hover:before, .shadow-box:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px lighten($black, 40%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Shadow #3</h2>
<div class="row shadow-3">
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/466x180">
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/466x180">
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/466x180">
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/466x180">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, fixed the problem! Out of interest - When position: relative is applied to the .shadow-box, it changes what the percent unit is valued at on the :after and :before even though the :before and :after have position: absolute. (I'm not sure if you understand that, it's kind of hard to explain - what I'm saying is when .shadow-box is relative, 10% width on :before and :after give them a thin width, but when .shadow-box doesn't have position relative, 10% width on the :before/:after is quite large). Why is this? Does the position of the parent affect the :before/after?

Comment: Setting position: relative; means "the child elements with position: absolute; will have the values relative to their parent". If no element in their parents has position: relative; their values will be relative to the body. I hope that makes sense. Take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/